# Show "no results" if searchbar filter has no results (HTML-CSS-JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a filter for my searchbar, how can I make it display "Sem resultado"("No Results" in portuguese) if the filter doesn't find any items with the letters typed?
This is my code, as you can see, I already have a HTML element for the "Sem resultado".

The searchbar might appear on the wrong place as I removed screen width responsiveness for this demo.
I hope the question isn't too confusing. Thank you in advance!

```js
function search(){
    var input, filter, dropdown, li, a, i, textvalue;
    input = document.getElementById('searchbarinput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    dropdown = document.getElementById("searchbardropdown");
    li = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('li');
    noresult = document.getElementById("searchbarnoresult");

    for(i=0; i < li.length; i++){
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        textvalue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if(textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)>-1){
            li[i].style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-title-container{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .dropdown-title{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    border: solid black 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    padding-right: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 290px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
  } 
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdowna{
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
a:hover{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.div{
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0vw 0vw 1vw black;
    margin: 1.5vw;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    padding: 0.5vw;
    padding-top: 0vw;
    padding-bottom: 0vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}
#trocarvariaveis{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
footer{
    margin-left: 2px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f0db4f;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
.headerdiv{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.backtotop{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.backtotoptext{
    margin: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.material-symbols-outlined{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: black;
}
.backtotop:hover .backtotoptext{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.backtotop:hover .material-symbols-outlined{
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}
.githubcontainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.githublink{
    color: black;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.githublink:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.searchbarcontainer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 125px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
.searchbarinput{
    height: 32px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    background-image: url('searchicon.svg');
    background-position: center left;
    background-size: 1.25em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 27px;
}
.searchbarinput:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.serchbarbutton{
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-left: none;
}
.material-symbols-outlined {
    font-variation-settings:
    'FILL' 0,
    'wght' 600,
    'GRAD' 0,
    'opsz' 48
  }
  .searchbarbuttonicon{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-self:center;
  }
  .searchbardropdown{
    display: none;
  }
  .searchbarinput:focus ~ .searchbardropdown{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 271px;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  .searchbardropdown:hover{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 271px;
    background-color: #f5f3e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: solid black 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  #searchbarnoresult{
    display: none;
  }
  #searchbarnoresult:hover{
    color: black;
  }
  ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .githublink2{
    color: black;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
.githublink2:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="javascriptlogo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,700,0,0" />
    <title>Javascript Exercicios | Maruan</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header id="myheader" class="sticky">
        <div class="headerdiv">
            <div class="backtotop">
                <a class="material-symbols-outlined" href="#" >arrow_upward</a>
                <a class="backtotoptext" href="#">Voltar ao topo</a>
              </div>
        <div class="githubcontainer">
            <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink">//GITHUB LINK</a>
            <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink2">//GITHUB</a>
        </div>
        <div class="searchbarcontainer">    
            <script src="searchbar.js"></script>
            <div class="searchbar">
            </div><input class="searchbarinput" id="searchbarinput" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar.." oninput="search()">
            <ul class="searchbardropdown" id="searchbardropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdowna" id="searchbarnoresult">Sem resultados<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#">Trocar Variaveis<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">Celsius para Farenheit<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">Farenheit para Celsius<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">Area Circulo<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">Par ou Impar<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">Intervalo entre numeros<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">Maior e menor numero<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">Paisagem ou retrato<br></a></li> 
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">Fizz ou Buzz<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">String do objeto<br></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">Par ou impar ate limite<br></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-title-container">
            <p class="dropdown-title">MENU</p>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#">// Trocar Variaveis<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">// Celsius para Farenheit<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">// Farenheit para Celsius<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">// Area Circulo<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">// Par ou Impar<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">// Intervalo entre numeros<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">// Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">// Maior e menor numero<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">// Paisagem ou retrato<br></a>  
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">// Fizz ou Buzz<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">// String do objeto<br></a>
              <a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">// Par ou impar ate limite<br></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Looks like nearly a direct copy-paste from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)... better to write code yourself or use a better resource, w3schools is almost always a worse option than either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you. I've added a data attribute (`data-no-search`) to skip the list element from the search, so `display: none` does not get set on the `li` element of the no search result element.

I add a flag to check if there are any matches, and if that flag is still false after iterating through all searchable elements, I add the `noResults` class to the dropdown list, and a CSS selector will unhide the no elements found element.

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, dropdown, li, a, i, textvalue;
  input = document.getElementById('searchbarinput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  dropdown = document.getElementById("searchbardropdown");
  li = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('li');

  let matches = false;
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].dataset.noSearch !== undefined) continue
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    textvalue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      matches = true
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  if (!matches) dropdown.classList.add('noResults');
  else dropdown.classList.remove('noResults');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-title-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 290px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdowna {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.div {
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0vw 0vw 1vw black;
  margin: 1.5vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  padding-top: 0vw;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}

#trocarvariaveis {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

footer {
  margin-left: 2px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f0db4f;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.headerdiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.backtotop {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.backtotoptext {
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.55em;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: black;
}

.backtotop:hover .backtotoptext {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.backtotop:hover .material-symbols-outlined {
  color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
}

.githubcontainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.githublink {
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.githublink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.searchbarcontainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 125px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchbarinput {
  height: 32px;
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  background-image: url('searchicon.svg');
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: 1.25em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

.searchbarinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.serchbarbutton {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-left: none;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 600, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48
}

.searchbarbuttonicon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-self: center;
}

.searchbardropdown {
  display: none;
}

.searchbarinput:focus~.searchbardropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 271px;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.searchbardropdown:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 271px;
  background-color: #f5f3e6;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

#searchbarnoresult {
  display: none;
}

.noResults #searchbarnoresult {
  display: block;
}

#searchbarnoresult:hover {
  color: black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.githublink2 {
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

.githublink2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="javascriptlogo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,700,0,0" />
  <title>Javascript Exercicios | Maruan</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="myheader" class="sticky">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <div class="backtotop">
        <a class="material-symbols-outlined" href="#">arrow_upward</a>
        <a class="backtotoptext" href="#">Voltar ao topo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="githubcontainer">
        <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink">//GITHUB LINK</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/maruan-achkar/javascript_exercicios" target="_blank" class="githublink2">//GITHUB</a>
      </div>
      <div class="searchbarcontainer">
        <script src="searchbar.js"></script>
        <div class="searchbar">
        </div><input class="searchbarinput" id="searchbarinput" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar.." oninput="search()">
        <ul class="searchbardropdown" id="searchbardropdown">
          <li data-no-search><a class="dropdowna" id="searchbarnoresult">Sem resultados<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#">Trocar Variaveis<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">Celsius para Farenheit<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">Farenheit para Celsius<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">Area Circulo<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">Par ou Impar<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">Intervalo entre numeros<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">Maior e menor numero<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">Paisagem ou retrato<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">Fizz ou Buzz<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">String do objeto<br></a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">Par ou impar ate limite<br></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-title-container">
          <p class="dropdown-title">MENU</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#">// Trocar Variaveis<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#trocarvariaveis">// Celsius para Farenheit<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#celsiusparafarenheit">// Farenheit para Celsius<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#farenheitparacelsius">// Area Circulo<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#areacirculo">// Par ou Impar<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#parouimpar">// Intervalo entre numeros<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalo">// Intervalo dentro de vetor<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#intervalovetor">// Maior e menor numero<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#maiormenor">// Paisagem ou retrato<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#paisagemouretrato">// Fizz ou Buzz<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#fizzbuzz">// String do objeto<br></a>
          <a class="dropdowna" href="#stringobject">// Par ou impar ate limite<br></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```